# Serilog doesn't create a file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, owin, serilog

I was given a task to add Logs to legacy .Net framework 4.8 ASP.Net Owin Project.

I tried to test-log into a 'log.txt' file using the code below but the file just wasn't created

```cs
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(WEB.Startup))]
namespace WEB
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR();
            Logger();
        }

        public void Logger()
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File("log.txt")/*
                .WriteTo
                .MSSqlServer(
                    connectionString: "Server=(local);Database=#;Integrated Security=false;User ID=#;Password=#;",
                    sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "LogEvents" })*/
                .CreateLogger();
            //Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(s => Console.WriteLine($"Internal Error with Serilog: {s}"));
            Log.Information("TESTTEST");

            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }
}
```

I added SelfLog in order to catch exceptions in Debug Output windows but there was nothing special.

I tried to google this problem, but suggestions were not helpful (for example Log.CloseAndFlush()).

I also made a test Asp.Net Core project to test the same code and it did work.

I have no clue what the problem is, if you have any suggestions please share them with me.

Comment: Shouldn't there be something like a `UseSerilog()` somewhere?

Comment: In the process of googling i found out, that UseSerilog() is not necessary, I confirmed that when tested logs in asp.net Core

Comment: Have you tried to initialize your logger in global.asax  Application_Start ?

Comment: @B.Lec I have tried this right now, no result

Comment: Where did you check for your log.txt file? Classic ASP.Net applications are always run by the webserver (IIS or IIS Express) which might give you some unexpected paths if you don't specify it correctly. Try adding an absolut path (or use `Server.MapPath("~/log.txt");` if it is available during startup) to make sure that you are writing the file to a known location.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren You were right, i added absolute path and it worked out, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I found that for ASP.NET framework 4.8 using IIS EXPRESS, the log files will get created in the IIS EXPRESS PROGRAM FILES folder.

C:\Program Files\IIS Express\